# SAWarning: Object of type <Child> not in session, add operation along 'Parent.children' will not proceed

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm stuck on this issue and I don't know how to fix it. This is my `models.py` file:

#### models.py

```
class TripDetail(db.Model):
    """
    Base class for every table that contains info about a trip.
    """
    __abstract__ = True
    __bind_key__ = 'instructions'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # list of fields    

class Overview(TripDetail):
    """
    Class that contains general information about a trip.
    """
    __tablename__ = 'overviews'
    __table_args__ = (
        db.ForeignKeyConstraint(['user_id', 'calendar_id'], ['calendars.user_id', 'calendars.id'], ondelete='CASCADE'),
    )  # constraints on other tables, omitted here
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    calendar_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    calendar = db.relationship('Calendar', backref=db.backref('overviews', cascade='delete'), passive_deletes=True)
    # other fields

class Step(TripDetail):
    __tablename__ = 'steps'

    overview_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('overviews.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    overview = db.relationship('Overview', backref=db.backref('steps', cascade='delete'), passive_deletes=True)
    # also other fields
```

And this is how I add items to the DB (the response parameter contains a dict that matches the classes, in such a way that it can be unpacked directly):

```
def add_instruction(response):
    """
    Adds a travel instruction to the database.
    """
    steps = response.pop('steps')
    overview = Overview(**response)
    for step in steps:
        Step(overview=overview, **step)
    db.session.add(overview)
    db.session.commit()
    logger.info(f"Stored instruction with PK {(overview.id, overview.user_id, overview.calendar_id, overview.event_id)}")
```

Now, the `overviews` table is filled up correctly, but `steps` stays empty. Inspecting the logs, I receive this warning:

> SAWarning: Object of type  not in session, add operation along 'Overview.steps' will not proceed
>     (orm_util.state_class_str(state), operation, prop))

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally, when `add()`ing objects to a session, their related objects will get auto-added like you wanted. That behavior is controlled by the relationship's [`cascade`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/cascades.html).

Setting `cascade` to `'delete'` in `Steps.overview` removes the default [`'save-update'`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/cascades.html#save-update), which is what turns on the auto-adding. You *could* just add it back with `cascade='save-update, delete'`, but take a look at the [possible traits](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/cascades.html) and see what else you might need. A common set is `'all, delete-orphan'`.

And remember these are strictly ORM behaviors; setting a `'delete'` in your cascade won't set the column's `ON [event] CASCADE`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I've solved this by expliciting adding the created step to the session. Still have no idea what the warning means though, so I'll just leave this here. My fix:

```
for step in steps:
    step = Step(overview=overview, **step)  # explicitly add
    db.session.add(step)
```