# SQLAlchemy 2.0: SAWarning: Object of type <Child> not in session, add operation along 'Parent.children' will not proceed

Tags: sqlalchemy

First off, this is not a duplicate of [an older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47912520/sawarning-object-of-type-child-not-in-session-add-operation-along-parent-ch) because the warning is back in SQA 2.0 and it doesn't go away with cascade configuration. I'm currently porting some code to SQA 2.0 and am stuck at this point. Here's a minimal runnable example:

```
from typing import List
from sqlalchemy.orm import (sessionmaker, Mapped, mapped_column,
                            DeclarativeBase, relationship)
from sqlalchemy import Integer, create_engine, ForeignKey

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    bars: Mapped[List["Bar"]] = relationship(back_populates="foo")

class Bar(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'bar'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('foo.id'), primary_key=True)
    foo: Mapped["Foo"] = relationship(back_populates="bars")

engine = create_engine("sqlite://")
Session = sessionmaker(engine)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

db = Session()
foo = Foo()
db.add(foo)
bar = Bar()
if (True):
    # This throws the warning
    bar.foo = foo
else:
    # This dowsn't
    foo.bars.append(bar)
db.commit()
```

Now it isn't so hard to find workarounds for this but I'm a bit irritated because the migration guide doesn't seem to mention this important change of behavior.

Comment: The warning in SQLAlchemy 1.4.47 is "RemovedIn20Warning: "Bar" object is being merged into a Session along the backref cascade path for relationship "Foo.bars"; in SQLAlchemy 2.0, this reverse cascade will not take place.  Set cascade_backrefs to False in either the relationship() or backref() function for the 2.0 behavior; or to set globally for the whole Session, set the future=True flag (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/s9r1) (Background on SQLAlchemy 2.0 at: https://sqlalche.me/e/b8d9)"

Comment: Thanks, I knew it had to be somewhere. It kind of makes sense (bio)logically; after all there first has to be a parent that children can be "appended" to (rather than creating children out of nothing and then assigning them parents).

Comment: @GordThompson Probably I am missing something, so which is the best way to avoid the warning, still setting the relation as bar.foo = foo ?

Comment: @ChristianSicari - Explicitly `db.add(bar)` before trying to update it.